# How to use PSD templates in Android for GUI

Tags: android

I have searched on the web for using PSD templates into the android but I am unable to find any website which demonstrate of how to use the PSD in android for GUI thing.
I have learnt that we need to copy the images from the PSD file and use it in our application but I have one doubt that if I use those images for example I found one login screen PSD file then my doubt is how i will make it interactive.

- How can i use the box to fill in username and password
- If i enter the text in username field and if its bigger than the png size will the text get implicitly fitted into the Box.

I know this is one of the basic question but everyone thinking of how to use it.
It would be nice if some tutorials or good links are provided.

Thanx SO users!!

Answer (score 2):

Right. Android doesn't support **psd** files. You have to save those files as **png**

Answers:

- Make an image the background for your EditText.
- To make them grow accordingly, you better create a 9 patch (which is a png with an extra 1 px border per side)

Link to a 9 patch tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Basically, you can use the left and upper border to define (in black) the stretchable area(s), vertical and horizontal, repectively.

Optionally, you can use the right and bottom side to mark the "content area" (to define paddings)

The file extension must be **.9.png**, not only **.png**

To add the borders, you do it in the graphical editor.
It's inside the png.
Just add a 1 px border (enlarge the canvas by 2px in both directions).

Not that the markers have to be **black** (#ff000000).

Comment: ...I have went through the 9 patch article..It basically says left and top defines stretchable areas as you mentioned...but my point is how do i set these extra 1px border per side in android

Comment: NO... you do it in the graphical editor. It's inside the png. Just add a 1 px border (enlarge the canvas by 2px in both directions). The markers have to be **black** (#ff000000).

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer and removing it from the Unanswered Question Queue... ;)